# Azure VM Metric

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, metrics

I am looking for a way to view CPU usage for multiple VMs on the same graph in Azure (new portal)?

So far I was only able to produce a graph showing metrics for 1 VM. I would like to achieve this for multiple VMs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

What I'm trying to recreate is the below:

[image]

Regards,J

Comment: Define Azure. Application Insights?

Comment: @TomTom Insights is not enabled so to answer your question, no not specifically though application insights. I need to view CPU metrics for multiple front end vms for the past 4 months. Is this achievable through Azure?

Comment: No. Generally: Yes, but you ahve to actually make the work BEFORE you need the data. Nothing that I Know of keeps 4 months stats "just in case" in azure. With application insights you could do it, but you would not magically get past data.

Comment: @TomTom I've updated my description with what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: Are they all part of the same cloud service? or are you using V2?

Comment: @CtrlDot They are 4 individual Classic VMs under the same subscription and resource group

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Azure OMS** to achieve your scenario.

With near real-time performance data collection, you can collect and visualize any performance counter in OMS. Simply entering the query **Type:Perf** will return thousands of metric graphs based on the number of counters and servers in your OMS environment. With on-demand metric aggregation, you can look at the overall metrics in your environment at a high level, and deep dive into more granular data as you need to.

You could perform the hourly average of CPU usage across all your computer as follows:

> Type:Perf CounterName="% Processor Time" ObjectName=Processor
>   InstanceName=_Total Computer IN {Type:Perf CounterName="% Processor
>   Time" ObjectName=Processor InstanceName=_Total | measure
>   avg(CounterValue) as AVG by Computer | Sort AVG Desc |Top 5} | measure
>   avg(CounterValue) by Computer Interval 5MINUTES

[image]

Please refer to the steps below.

1.Create Log Analytics resource in your resource group.

2.Connect your VMs to this workspace.
[image]
3. Get metrics in OMS Portal.

More information about OMS please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-searches)

Comment: I find a good article about your scenario, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msoms/2016/02/26/on-demand-metric-aggregation-and-visualization-in-oms/

Comment: thanks for the info. I will be experimenting with OMS in the near future as it seems to be a good product. My next hurdle is to export azure metrics. Any experience with exporting results ?

Comment: Yes, you could. On my screenshot, you could see  "Export" button, it is a .csv file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is this not achievable with the standard Azure metrics feature ?

Comment: Yes. For now, Azure does not support multiple VMs on the same graph with the standard Azure metrics feature.

Comment: Classic VMs support connect to OMs if they are in the same region.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Already marked your answer as helpful, however I did not use it in the end (even though I will be testing OMS in the near future). I used metrics for Cloud Services (Since VMs were classic VMs); and even there metrics were unavailable for a specific timeframe during which then resources were definitely operational. Thanks again for your input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50517/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-joebegborg07).